# How to run a Qt application in background on Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, qt, process

I want to make a application in Qt for Android and I have this problem: when user press "back" button, my application receives a QCloseEvent and it is killed. I want the application to run in background, something like a service or daemon. How can I do that?

Comment: Using a GUI framework for something that should run in the background seems counter-intuitive. Maybe use a android service?

Comment: I want to make an Alarm Clock application.

Comment: Having a Qt app running in the background is overkill for that purpose. Read up on [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

Creating [Android Services](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/androidservices.html) has been added to Qt in version 5.7.